# fread and fwrite have difference result

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I am using fread to read from a file and then use fwrite to write to anothe file. but content of the new file is slightly different from the content of the old file (the new file have a lot more character), do you know what can cause this and how to fix it?

to read

```
file= fopen(locationHolder[x], "r");    
chunkToSend.chunkcontent.data = malloc(20000);
chunkToSend.chunkcontent.len = fread(chunkToSend.chunkcontent.data , 1, 20000, file);
```

to write

```
file =  fopen(filelocation, "w"); 
fwrite(responseChunk->chunkcontent.data, 1, responseChunk->chunkcontent.len, file);
```

this is the file I am reading:

```
†+ƒCÃÅ«*u`‘Ÿ‘Ž÷-U‰ÎVøÈ  ýÇ}‡3²SûYè³…öeŠ
5êèMØ“—­~K¾ëb–Ü†º[ö¿äWÔM)
ø˜i ¯’#\×b!¥^b€÷ûƒãq.]…©\.u7Ã˜¨øöÔv´cgÒD–o_ÊûG}^ªmÞŸ}ÛåŒ}?Ž…WíëH
?Íƒ>—”*î`ÔÿïÖtàNÕ$Cú¾@Ž›¿Žíohy5ÅE5qØ²9¡_Sé›‰+þ¦¥²‘*Jíf†
#¸«vÌÏ  s¼üEÃe+vLrF¯Gå3šú¦Ì×Mçó
<f¥#ÇyEBŠ1iÉŒ6pZa›MSÅîl:ôšËÄ§   
Jþ}ÜÍÃÑ1˜´+$fÌ†\Ø$±)sæâ¼üõÅ‘Ï™Àd–ÚDM*Ì
R¯èÕ¼£C†}—
¸mÝ¼ž„ª1øL5E‰_ð7âHö:´¡`¼E[Ö<BJüR’½Ê€“%8p
LÄ] ¡û2ì––û}ðCÓîŽBáæeÎøëåZ§ "
[Òºèf¯Œÿ»'L"g‚æ°C«G§¸IŸ‰ˆÚ‘_´G’.ÂÝp¯K%RÕlÍâ3÷À+\9rØ‚/Ë±V¨?Ù}Ü¨›`l½î~RŽbŒ—w˜[£¦2™¾RÿÁeÎPbeö‘¿±¤N#Oåãº&
Êc9OËbÿÊ3ÚVâ›©²TPdx»ÉbèÁW8×MAà¥ó]D
å™QØè’¿=Ÿ±­$BºÀŒdž\3âZ³‰×…×‰…¹dØ¾íÂÂÎA^Ç¦èÕ`±³ï
<µ¡QGÙY—-p÷›AÂ+pžD‘©ûÊÄÉ÷¢y×çÃt…ˆæîYiGÇÊAðÁô¡4YWoâ=ÊÁ+¤·•Ï)ùïéÚTVî±0ME¡{Èÿ‚.G°Ágª¯‚É9&­ê¡ÑUIÃÄ¤b†§JâY&_SæþJãi›©'È›XA’M[dY&²AbîAëfG½€oN(oM+CzíµÚ
```

this is the file I wrote:

```
†+ƒCÃÅ«*u`‘Ÿ‘Ž÷-U‰ÎVøÈ  ýÇ}‡3²SûYè³…öeŠ
5êèMØ“—­~K¾ëb–Ü†º[ö¿äWÔM)
ø˜i ¯’#\×b!¥^b€÷ûƒãq.]…©\.u7Ã˜¨øöÔv´cgÒD–o_ÊûG}^ªmÞŸ}O…ªœ¦ÛåŒ}?Ž…WíëH
?Íƒ>—”*î`ÔÿïÖtàNÕköR,E·$Cú¾@Ž›¿Žíohy5ÅE5qØ²9¡_Sé›‰+þ¦¥²‘*Jíf†
#¸«vÌÏ  s¼üEÃe+vLrßÞ¾"ò1%áoÌû/êF¯Gå3šú¦Ì×Mçó
<f¥#ÇyEBŠ1iÉŒ6pZa›MSÅîl:ôšËÄ§   
Jþ}ÜÍÃÑ1˜´+$fÌ†\Ø$±)sæâ¼üõÅ‘Ï™Àd–ÚDM*Ì
R¯èÕ¼£C†}—
¸mÝ¼ž„ª1øL5E‰_ð7âHö:´¡`¼E[Ö<BJüR’½Ê€“%8p
LÄ] ¡û2ì––û}ðCÓîŽBáæeÎøëåZ§ "
[Òºèf¯Œÿ»'L"g‚æ°C«G§¸IŸ‰ˆÚ‘_´G’.§b[•’KÛ0I¼û´)•Á
é_“Ä*ÂÝp¯K%RÕlÍâ3÷À+\9rØ‚/Ë±V¨?Ù}Ü¨›`l½î~RŽbŒ—w˜[£¦2™¾RÿÁeÎPbeö‘¿±¤N#Oåãº&
Êc9OËbÿÊ3ÚVâ›©²TPdx»ÉbèÁW8×MAà¥ó]D
å™QØè’¿=Ÿ±­$BºÀŒdž\3âZ³‰×…×‰…¹dØ¾íÂÂÎA^Ç¦èÕ`±³ï
<µ¡QGÙY—-p÷›AÂ+pžD‘©ûÊÄÉ÷¢y×çÃt…ˆæîYiGÇÊAðÁô¡4YWoâ=ÊåÓñš‰Ö_”]Â½ÅÛô8ª<‡·gœ¡C`øm¼Á+¤·•Ï)ùïéÚTVî±0ME¡{Èÿ‚.G°Ágª¯‚É9&­©pöïMâF³°Ä}à–+iä0;ˆ7Y|Å4u¹SFŸwê¡ÑUIÃÄ¤b†§JâY&_SæþJãi›©'È›XA’M[dY&²AbîAë[‚þ%\6¿ÿ=î…Èq‚ÌÉ$é“o
àƒž“ªÔ~ºÐ¹ÿÔ_löfG½€oN(o§ƒþ7Í
Âý0«F\!¡Ä¹\ÙoÑ,¼W™´CC#mà]
```

**------never mind, figured out the problem. If you open the same file on window and linux, they still look different. I open the old file on windows while I open the new file linux.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: Is this on MS Windows?  If so, you have to replicate the text/binary mode on open.

Comment: try to `memset(chunkToSend.chunkcontent.data, 0, 20000)` first

Comment: Since the files are binary, it would be far better to show the output of a binary difference (rather than the file content).  On Unix/Linux, just use `diff`.  On Windows, use the command `fc`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read and write the files as binary on a Windows system, you'll need to specify that when you open them for reading:

```
file=fopen("source", "rb");
```

and for writing:

```
file=fopen("target", "wb");
```

Also, don't forget to check to see if the opens succeeded before using the filehandle.  (`file != NULL`)

Comment: First, you haven't said what kind of system you're using.  Second, in your question, those aren't "files".  That's just junk you've cut-and-pasted from something you're using to view them.  Where are they the same?  Where are they different?  Use a proper tool to compare binary files and find out.  The most common reason for differences are newline characters and nulls (but reading/writing in binary can avoid).  Lastly, this is poor code.  You're not checking the return of `fwrite` to see what was actually written.  Write a *small* program to copy the same data and post the entire thing here.